# Count the duplicate words in a text mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, search, text

How do I count the appearance of a word in a text-column in MySQL?

Example:

Row-Data:

> "This is a test text for testing"

Word:

> "test"

Output:

> --> 2 Matches

I want to calculate the relevance of a word in datasets. Therefore I need to know how often a certain column contains the search-phrase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select (length(column)-length(replace(column,'test','')))/4 as COUNT 
FROM table
```

Replace 4 with the number of letters in your word.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15f087/1)

Comment: A better written SQL would be instead of 4, to write LENGTH('test') which is the same value, but explains better the logic, cheers for the answer